# Operation on sublists with multiple arguments

Tags: list-manipulation, map, iterators

I have a list and add only the values which are > 0 with:

```
Total[Cases[mylist, x_ /; x > 0]]
```

How to do this if I now have a list of sublists?

```
Map[Total[Cases[???, x_ /; x > 0]], mylistoflists]
```

I tried to use `#` (to reference the actual sublist) which doesn't work. I tried `##` (to reference all values of the actual sublist) which doesn't work.

So, how can I reference the actual list while iterating over all sublists?

Comment: What exactly have you tried with `#`? You might want to read http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html

Comment: It is possible that I do not understand your question. Please give a sample input and the corresponding desired output.  E.g. here's an input: `mylistoflists = {{-1, 2, -3, 4}, {-4, 3, -2, 1}}`. I'll wait with writing an answer until you respond.

Comment: So, what's wrong with `Map[Total[Cases[#, x_ /; x > 0]] &, mylistoflists]` (notice the `&`)? Btw., `Total[Ramp[mylistoflists], {2}]` should be a faster way to accomplish your goals (by a speed factor of 100 or so).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks! I was missing the & as I thought Mathematica would implicitly a pure function. Ramp looks good too. Is there a function of the same concept for x <= 0?